# Tomcat starts in eclipse without my app deployed but when I do deploy it, BOOM

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Here's the deal: I've search S.O. high and low for similar problems and although the titles are the same as my ERROR log shows, nothing tells me what exactly the problem is, since I'm relatively new to AP/TOM but a 53 yr old, old-guy programmer.

```
Error 1: - WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MGMTSYS-UIC' did not find a matching property.

Error 2: - SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MGMTSYS-UIC]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MGMTSYS-UIC]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> App.jsp in filter mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2975)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2924)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

----------------------- END OF ERRORS

I'm running E.KEPLER version and AP/TOM 8.03 I believe... it's not 7

Again, what you're seeing above the the error I receive when I deploy my app to the server to run.

Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.

Ciao,

Peter

UPDATE:

Here's the new error as things have changed and I have solved the above problem with configuration:

```
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 8\;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\csvn\bin\;C:\csvn\Python25\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS LIVE;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS LIVE;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS LIVE\SHARED;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\WIFI\BIN\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\INTEL\WIRELESSCOMMON\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;.
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MDI UI' did not find a matching property.
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 701 ms
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42-RC4
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4744)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5276)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/MDI_UI] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 09, 2013 7:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1597 ms
```

Here's the Web.XML

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.mkyong.common
    SpringMVC
    war
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    SpringMVC Maven Webapp

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mavenVersion>2.1</mavenVersion>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>MGMTSYS_UI</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The exception says: Invalid App.jsp in filter mapping. So the filter mapping has a problem. Please add the web.xml to your question.

Comment: Something is terribly wrong, here. You say you are running Tomcat 8.0.0-RC3 (there is not yet an 8.0.3) but the log says 7.0.42-RC4 (I have no idea where the RC4 came from... there is no such version). The stack trace says it can't find `ServletContextListener`, but that should be provided by the container. How are you launching Tomcat? Have you put `servlet*.jar` into your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory or something similar? Tomcat should protect against that, but it's possible that Spring is doing some of its own class-loading...

Comment: I'm launching Tomcat through command prompt window not through NetBeans, which is what I'm using for my IDE now. Dumped Eclipse... it sucks.

Comment: This is the only error I'm getting now:   SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-16] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed.  I'm running Tomcat 8.0 RC1... the RC4 was a mistake when I inputted a FRIENDLY NAME for the server.  I just need to resolve this error and I've searched high and low to no avail. I'm using SpringMVC as the framework and MAVEN.  All my spring framework JARs are loaded perfectly.  Plus my common and jstl JARs.  I have removed all the deprecated "older" jars and went with the 3.x versions...